# Не работает django static

Tags: django

Такая проблема, начал новый проект на джанге - не могу запустить в нём static files.

settings.py

```
...
'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
...
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# эта переменная будет указывать на папку проекта
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))#os.path.join( os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..' )

# путь до папки media, в общем случае она пуста в начале
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'  # URL для медии в шаблонах
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')  # пустая папка, сюда будет собирать статику collectstatic
STATIC_URL = '/static/'  # URL для шаблонов
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/interface/')),
    url(r'^interface/', include('interface.urls',namespace="interface")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) \
  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Причем по ссылке media все работает, файлы открываются, а по ссылке static получаю 404 от джанги.

Comment: Если есть - киньте свой рабочий проект в котором работают статические файлы на имэйл ryzyi.kot@yandex.ru

Comment: А `collectstatic` выполняли? Отрабатывает нормально?

Comment: collectstatic выполнился, скопировал в папку static файло админки

Comment: Выведите `PROJECT_ROOT` в консоль. У вас там тот путь, что нужен?

Comment: Вы описали папку статики в staticfiles_dirs? Если да, то попробуйте заменить строку пути к ней - захардкодьте этот путь, пропишите ваш текущий абсолютный путь. И скажите, изменилось что-нибудь или нет.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было добавить ещё одну строку в переменную STATICFILES_FINDERS.

По итогу, чтобы заработали статические файлы нужно в settings.py прописать:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```